# Facebook like button rendering under other content

Tags: css, facebook-like

I administer a [fairly popular cooking blog](http://www.enmicocinahoy.cl) in Spanish, and this is driving me crazy. The Facebook Like button (pulled in through the AddThis plugin for Wordpress, but to the best of my knowledge actual Facebook code) renders underneath other content. I'm at my wits' end. Here's what it looks like when someone clicks the "Like" button (in Firefox, Google, or Safari, it doesn't matter)

[I don't have enough reputation to post images, so here's a link to a screenshot of the problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2131541/emch_regular_view.png)

(Note the little callout under the "like" button)

If I twiddle that div's settings using the object inspector and make its height larger it renders correctly.

However, I can't get this to happen correctly by itself and, to the best of my knowledge, it should "just render".

I suspect it has something to do with my theme (Agency on top of the Genesis Framework for Wordpress), but I can't find what to change. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Just a note. It displayed fine for me in Chrome, Mac OS X.

Comment: Even weirder; it doesn't, for me, in Chrome on Mac OS X.

Comment: Can't get it to show on two different computers, both running OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see those buttons on your home page at all, but you could try removing this code, as it's not really needed but will cut off the box below the like button:

```
.entry-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I thought I had tried this, but I was changing overflow for other elements. This did the trick.